# Переадресовывать запросы URL в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Ссылка на страницу была такого вида:

*старый URL*

```
http://www.site.ru/?Page_best:Article_One
```

Я изменил ссылку на такой вид:

*новый URL*

```
http://www.site.ru/?Page_best/Article_One
```

**Вопрос**

Как в файле .htaccess переадресовывать запросы с внешних ссылок со старого URL

```
 http://www.site.ru/?Page_best:Article_One
```

на новый URL?

```
http://www.site.ru/?Page_best/Article_One
```

Такой способ не переадресовывает:

```
Redirect 301 /?Page_best:Article_One http://www.site.ru/?Page_best/Article_One
```

Все остальные способы пятисотые.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, вот такая штука должна работать

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+):(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ /?%1/%2 [L]
```

Если надо именно Page_best:Article_One

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Page_best:Article_One$
RewriteRule ^ /?Page_best/Article_One [L]
```